# Changing a 2D array to jagged array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

In my code, I've using a 2D multidimensional array to represent a grid (not always of equal sizes, eg 10x15 or 21x7). After reading about how jagged arrays are faster and are generally considered better, I decided I would change my 2D array into a jagged array.

This is how I declared the multidimensional array:

```
int[,] array = new int[10, 10];
```

I'm trying to figure out how to declare and then initialise the same thing, but using jagged arrays.

**Edit** This code is inside a class, and in the constructor I already have:

```
class ProceduralGrid
{
    private int[][] grid;

    private int _columns;
    private int _rows;

    public ProceduralGrid(int rows, int columns)
    {
        _rows = rows;             //For getters
        _columns = columns;

        //Create 2D grid
        int x, y;
        grid = new int[rows][];

        for (x = 0; x < grid.Length; x++)
        {
            grid[x] = new int[10];
        }
    }

    public int GetXY(int rows, int columns)
    {
        if (rows >= grid.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
        {

            throw new ArgumentException("Passed X value (" + rows.ToString() +
                ") was greater than grid rows (" + grid.GetUpperBound(0).ToString() + ").");
        }
        else
        {
            if (columns >= grid.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)
            {

                throw new ArgumentException("Passed Y value (" + columns.ToString() +
                    ") was greater than grid columns (" + grid.GetUpperBound(1).ToString() + ").");
            }
            else
            {
                return grid[rows][columns];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in another method I'm simply doing:

```
    Console.WriteLine(grid.GetXY(5, 5).ToString());
```

Error message I'm getting:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array does not have that m
any dimensions.
   at System.Array.GetUpperBound(Int32 dimension)
   at ProcGen.ProceduralGrid.GetXY(Int32 rows, Int32 columns) in C:\Users\Lloyd\
documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ProcGen\ProcGen\ProceduralGrid.cs:line 115
   at ProcGen.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Lloyd\documents\visual stu
dio 2010\Projects\ProcGen\ProcGen\Program.cs:line 27
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I be doing it?

Comment: Not sure what `GetLength(0)` is supposed to do, but you could just use `grid.Length`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're dealing with one-dimensional arrays, you can simply use the [Length Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) to get the length of the first dimension:

```
int[][] grid = new int[10][];

for (int x = 0; x < grid.Length; x++)
{
    grid[x] = new int[10];
}
```

(Using the [GetLength Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) works as well:)

```
int[][] grid = new int[10][];

for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    grid[x] = new int[10];
}
```

---

The problem with your code is that you're calling `grid.GetUpperBound(1)` where `grid` is a one-dimensional array -- it doesn't have a second dimension (index 1) that you could get the upper bound of.

Your GetXY method should look like this:

```
public int GetXY(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= grid.Length)
    {
        throw ...
    }

    int[] items = grid[x];

    if (y < 0 || y >= items.Length)
    {
        throw ...
    }

    return items[y];
}
```

Note that jagged arrays are not magic that makes your code faster – measure if they actually do!

Comment: To clarify, this code is in a class, and in the class constructor I already have private int[][] grid; I forgot to mention that bit.

Comment: Then I'm not sure where your error messages comes from. Can you add the code for a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem? What's the error message you're receiving exactly?

Comment: Ok, I have added the class.

Comment: Ok thanks, that work's great! I also have a SetXY value that is identical to the GetXY that I posted, how would I go about changing that?

Comment: Replace `return items[y];` with `items[y] = value;`.